# ACM ICPC how to use PC^2?

Tags: java, io, file

Yesterday we had a practice on the PC^2 it is the official judge software for the contest but I had a problems with it, my code for the problem is correct and the answer is correct but when I send it to the software it answer me "Runtime Error".

I think my problem in the input file they wanted the input from input file and stranded output, it was my first time to handle with files so I went to the default package then new > other >empty> then I fill the file with the inputs then I wrote this code and it's working 100% on my pc then I submit it via the pc^2 I send the .java file only as they said, but it told me runtime error.

Here is the problem [problem B](http://www.ahmed-aly.com/p.jsp?ID=72) but they want the input from a file anyone who have an experience with that software help me please.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class omar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\omar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\omar\\src\\omar.in"));
        int t = n.nextInt();
        int x;
        char o;
        int y;
        int z;
        int res;
        String[] c = new String[t];
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            x = n.nextInt();
            o = n.next().charAt(0);
            y = n.nextInt();
            n.next();
            z = n.nextInt();
            if (o == '+') {
                res = x + y;
            } else {
                res = x - y;
            }
            if (res == z) {
                c[i] = "YES";
            } else {
                c[i] = "NO";
            }
        }
        int counter = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Case" + " " + counter + ":" + " " + c[j]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner n = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\omar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\omar\\src\\omar.in"));
```

This is where the file is located in your computer. That won't help you at all when running the program on a Judge's computer. You need to open the file from where the contest's instruction said it would be.